# Move product custom options section after Cart button

Tags: magento, layout, magento2

I want to move product custom options section below add to cart button. I am using Luma theme. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In your `/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout` folder, create a `catalog_product_view.xml`

Inside the `<body>` tag you can use the move directive to rearrange the standard layout from Luma. This should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" destination="product.info.form.options" before="product.info.options.wrapper"></move>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also, refer to magento devdocs on this topic: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

From an e-commerce point of view though I can't think of a single usecase where this would be intuitive and good usablity. But that is offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with the help of @pritim Info 24.
Here is the link:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251722/magento-2-how-to-move-custom-options-after-cart-button